Equivalent to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
This is a question form a sample paper whose solutions where not published:

Let $a$ and $b$ be two nonzero vectors in $3$ dimensions. The orthogonal projection of $b$ onto $a$ is$$c=(e\cdot b)e,$$where $e=\frac{a}{\Vert a\Vert}$ is the unit vector in the direction of $a$, and $\Vert a\Vert$ denotes the length of $a$.
(A) If $b-c$ is nonzero then $|(a\cdot b)|=\Vert a\Vert\Vert b\Vert$.
(B) If $b-c$ is zero then $|(a\cdot b)|<\Vert a\Vert\Vert b\Vert$.
(C) $\Vert b-c\Vert\ge0$ is equivalent to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
(D) None of the above

where I have doubt is the option C, I want to understand what it is trying to say when it says "is equivalent to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality" and is the option C correct? I know what Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is, as per my knowledge it states that, "the dot product of two vectors is less than/equal to the multiplication of magnitudes of the individual vectors". I know the question is easy and maybe all I have is the lack of understanding of the language. But I would really appreciate a response. Thank you

Please don't post pictures.

I am sorry I am new to using stack, but what's wrong with posting pictures?

Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. MathJax allows you to type up the question nicely. I've edited it accordingly.

@J.G. Thank you so much
